# Load Sms from inbox for specific number

Tags: android, list, sms

I have implemented the code to get sms from inbox to my app.It gets all messages.But I want to load messages from specific number.I followed the tutorial from [Read all SMS from a particular sender it shows empty view.I worked out this code.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.inbox);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        List<String> msgList = getSMS();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, msgList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

 }
        public List<String> getSMS() {
            List<String> sms = new ArrayList<String>();
            // StringBuilder smsBuilder = new StringBuilder();
       final String SMS_URI_INBOX = "content://sms/inbox"; 
       final String SMS_URI_ALL = "content://sms/";  
        try {  
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(SMS_URI_INBOX);  
            String[] projection = new String[] { "_id", "address", "person", "body", "date", "type" };  
         Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, "address='5558'", null, null);


         if (cur.moveToFirst()) {  
                             int index_Address = cur.getColumnIndex("address");  
                             int index_Person = cur.getColumnIndex("person");  
                             int index_Body = cur.getColumnIndex("body");  
                             int index_Date = cur.getColumnIndex("date");  
                             int index_Type = cur.getColumnIndex("type");       
                             do {  
                                 String strAddress = cur.getString(index_Address);  
                                 int intPerson = cur.getInt(index_Person);  
                                 String strbody = cur.getString(index_Body);  
                                 long longDate = cur.getLong(index_Date);  
                                 int int_Type = cur.getInt(index_Type); 



                                 sms.add("Number: " + strAddress + " .Message: " + strbody);

                               //  smsBuilder.append("[ ");  
                              //   smsBuilder.append(strAddress + ", ");  
                               //  smsBuilder.append(intPerson + ", ");  
                                // smsBuilder.append(strbody + ", ");  
                                // smsBuilder.append(longDate + ", ");  
                                 //smsBuilder.append(int_Type);  
                                // smsBuilder.append(" ]\n\n");  
                             } while (cur.moveToNext());  

                             if (!cur.isClosed()) {  
                                 cur.close();  
                                 cur = null;  
                             }  
                          else {  
                            // smsBuilder.append("no result!");  
                         } // end if  

                     }} catch (SQLiteException ex) {  
                         Log.d("SQLiteException", ex.getMessage());  

                     }
                     return sms;
                }
```

I passed address as my another emulator.If I gave null replacing address field of getContentResolver()it will load all sms in inbox.Can anyone help me where I have to modify ?

Answer (score 6):

Use following code,

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");

ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

String phoneNumber = "+911234567890";
String sms = "address='"+ phoneNumber + "'";
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, new String[] { "_id", "body" }, sms, null,   null);

System.out.println ( cursor.getCount() );

while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
{
    String strbody = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex("body") );
    System.out.println ( strbody );
}
```

Following permission is required,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
```

Comment: Can I use emulator port number like 5558 instead of mobile number?

Comment: Do you have sms in your emulator's inbox ?

Comment: What does this line `System.out.println ( cursor.getCount() );` prints ?

Comment: yeah I received sms from another emulator...if i gave all values of getContent Resolver to null it will load all messages...

Comment: oh, I think you should specify the emulator's number from which you have sent the sms. I am assuming you are using current emulator's port number.

Comment: No mu current emulator num is 5556 and another ones is 5558

Comment: ok, and what version of android you are using ? Let me try this in my emulator. I have tested code in phone and it is working fine.

Comment: android 4.2.2...api 17

Comment: Ok, I got it, in my emulator it is adding this number 1555521 before the 5554 so when I applied phoneNumber = "15555215554" it is working fine, try in your code as well and let me know the result.

Comment: I got the count as 9..But name,person and date all the things are not printed

Answer (score 0):

> 100% working code :

```
   String[] projection = new String[] { "_id", "thread_id","address", "person", "body", "date", "type" };
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");



    Cursor c = cr.query(uri, projection,"address='9876543210'",null, "date desc");

    int totalSMS = 0;
    if (c != null) {
        totalSMS = c.getCount();
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            for (int j = 0; j < totalSMS; j++) {

                String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Telephony.Sms._ID));
                String thread_id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Telephony.Sms.THREAD_ID));
                String smsDate = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Telephony.Sms.DATE));
                String number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Telephony.Sms.ADDRESS));
                String body = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Telephony.Sms.BODY));


                String type;

                switch (Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Telephony.Sms.TYPE)))) {
                    case Telephony.Sms.MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX:
                        type = "inbox";
                        messageList.add(new Message(id, thread_id, number, body, smsDate, type));
                        break;
                    case Telephony.Sms.MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT:
                        type = "sent";
                        messageList.add(new Message(id, thread_id, number, body, smsDate, type));
                        break;
                    case Telephony.Sms.MESSAGE_TYPE_OUTBOX:
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                c.moveToNext();
            }
        }

        c.close();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.